# How can you run a correlation coefficient test among two ordinal variables with uneven scales?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

I have two ordinal variables which are set on different scales. The variables were extracted from a  questionnaire. The first variable ranges from -12 to +12 with a step of 1 width, ( -12, -11,...-2,-1 , 0, 1, 2,..., +11, +12) and the second one ranges only from -2 to +2 with the same step width(-2,-1,0,+1,+2). I would like to investigate whether they correlate and also measure the strength of a potential association between them. How do I do this? Do I have to standardise the variables in order to compare them to each other? Thank you in advance,
Konstantinos

Comment: Paying attention to how wide is the `step width` exposes that one actually thinks his scales are interval, not ordinal. Ordinal scales do not have a defined step width, albeit they do differ in respect to the number of levels (=categories, =points): some are more grained and some are less.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. Still, how would these variables be compared to each other?

Answer (score 3):

[Polychoric correlations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation) were developed for precisely this problem.  There are implementations in R.